# The code won't recognize my if statement (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

The code wont recognize my if statement. When i run this code, i enter the following number: -10. However, this returns the else statement, when it should return the if statement. Any help with what i am doing wrong?

```
def distance_from_zero(d):
    if type(d)== int or type(d)==float:
        return abs(d)
    else:
        return "Not an integer or float!"
x = raw_input("Enter number: ")        
print distance_from_zero(d)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't recognize my if statement?" Please edit your question and be more specific. Is it raising an error message? If so, include the stack trace in your question. Is it giving you an unexpected output? If so, edit your question to include the input, the expected result as well as the result you received instead.

Comment: You probably want that last line to be `print distance_from_zero(x)`, right?

Comment: @MarkHildreth nope it isn't raising an error message. I edited the question.

Comment: @Brionius yep yep sorry.. -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`raw_input` always returns a string.  So if you type the number 9, it doesn't return the integer `9`, it returns the string `"9"`.  Therefore your test `type(d)== int or type(d)==float` is never true.

You could do something like

```
def distance_from_zero(d):
    try:
        return abs(int(d))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return abs(float(d))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return "Not an integer or float!"
x = raw_input("Enter number: ")        
print distance_from_zero(x)
```

This makes use of a design philosophy popular in python called "duck typing", in which, rather than test to see what an object's type is, you just treat the object as whatever type you want it to be and handle the exception that pops up if it isn't that type.

Answer (score 0):

Raw input returns a string, not an int or float. Try type casting  the variable you get from raw_input() so it is set to be an int or float.

Answer (score 0):

`x` will always be a `string` as it comes from `raw_input`.

> Help on built-in function raw_input in module **builtin**:
>
> raw_input(...)
>       raw_input([prompt]) -> string
>
> ```
> Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
> If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
> On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
> is printed without a trailing newline before reading. (END)
> ```